# Unknown notation for preimage

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

[image]

I can not understand the sign. Can anyone please let me know what I am supposed to show?

Comment: Maybe you need review the notation of the book that you're using for the course.

Comment: It is likely the pre-image, i.e. $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B \cap f(X)$

Comment: I think they simply mean $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B \cap f(X)$.

Comment: You will find this preimage left arrow notation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics))

Comment: @jean-marie What about converting this comment to an answer?

Comment: @J.-E. Pin Usually a one-line comment doesn't deserve to be transformed into an answer. It is true that it fully answers the OP's question...

Comment: @Jean-Marie Just look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22411/89374).

Comment: @JeanMarie It is not clear from the wikipedia. What I understood from the previous comments is $f^{\leftarrow} (B)= \{x \in X : f(x) \in B\}$. Is it right? Here $f: X \to Y$ and $B \subset Y$ .